# Android SQLITE - how to get days in week (mo..su) with hour with highest count of rows for current day of the week?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, max, distinct

I have the following table structure:
[image]

And I would like to get result like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAY | HOUR | DIALS_CNT | APPT_CNT | CONVERS_CNT | CANNOT_REACH_CNT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1 (note:means monday) | 13 | 20   |      10     |       5         | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | 8    | 30        | 15       | 7           |       13
-------------------------------------------------------------------
3   | 8    | 30        | 15       | 7           |       13
-------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | 0    | 0         | 0        | 0           |       0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

etc..(zero means that in data is no available value for 4 day = thursday, (wednesday if 0 is Sunday) ).

I tried to do it by this way:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT strftime('%w', dc.date) as day,
   strftime('%H', dc.date) as hour,
  COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'APPT_CNT',  
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CONVERS_CNT' ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CANNOT_REACH_CNT'  
FROM dialed_calls dc  
GROUP BY 
  strftime('%w', dc.date),
  strftime('%H', dc.date)
```

But without luck because i always get result like this:

[image]

How can i update query to get correct results?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: And what is the problem with this query?

Comment: Hello, I just updated my question.